# Remove objects from array - Two different approaches, two different results when consulting the length of each array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two identical arrays: `itemsOutput`& `itemsOutput2`

I want to delete those objects in the arrays with `attributes.type = "DIMENSION"`. I have found two different methods for doing so:

**Method 1**

```
jQuery.each(itemsOutput, function(i, val) {
    if(val.attributes.type == "DIMENSION") // delete index
      {
        delete itemsOutput[i];
      }
});
console.log(itemsOutput.length);
```

**Method 2**

```
metrics = itemsOutput2.filter(function (el) {
            return el.attributes.type === "METRIC";
          });
console.log(metrics.length);
```

Although both new arrays seem  to have the same number of objects (and in both, all objects with attributes.type = "DIMENSION" are gone), the console shows two totally different values for the length of each array.

Method 1 removes the objects, but length is the same as the original array (although exploring the array in the console I observe that the objects keep their original indexes)

Method 2 not only removes the objects, but it also reassings the indexes successively. And for me, the code seems more clear, so I will stay with this method.

My question is, however, why this happens and if there could be problems if I use the results of method 1 in a loop, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you delete an array element, [the array length is not affected](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements). This holds even if you delete the last element of the array. When the delete operator removes an array element, that element is no longer in the array but the length stays the same.

You will need to use method [splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) if you want to remove it from the array. For example:

```
itemsOutput.splice(i, 1);
```

Comment: I dont know how jQuery.each works but... If it loops over the objects starting from the beginning it could cause errors if you start using splice on the array mid-loop.

Comment: *the array will contain an undefined value at that index* ? Not really.

Comment: At least in firefox it looks like that is correct @DavidDormain. I opened the console and ran the following commands... `var test = [1, 2, 3, 4];`, `delete test[2];` test prints `Array [ 1, 2, <1 empty slot>, 4 ]`, then `test[2]===undefined `prints `true`

Comment: Your answer made me stringify the array, and you are totally right. This is the beginning of the stringified output: `"[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{"id":"ga:users","kind":"analytics#column","attributes":{"type":"METRIC"...`. So, method 1 needs an extra step if you want a "cleaner" array? I think that I will stay with method 2 :)

Comment: @Amir - `console.log(test[100])` will return `undefined` as well.

Comment: The array will not contain an undefined value at that index. It will become sparse, i.e. "have a hole" at that index. Yes, trying to read the value at that index will return undefined, but not because the array contains undefined at that position, but simply because there is nothing at that position. But the array still keeps the same length. Welcome to the absurd world of Javascript arrays!

Comment: @jcaron - Thank you. This is exactly the case here. [**Deleting array elements**](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Deleting_array_elements)

Comment: Fair enough, I didnt know that. @Amir Yep, decrementing gets around any nastiness caused by modifying the array while you are looping over it lol

Comment: @jcaron will that mean that using this array in a loop will "perform" worse than using another "not sparsed" array with identical information, as the loop will also iterate all the "holes"? Not a big thing for small arrays, but for larger ones

Comment: @agustin depends how you iterate. If you iterate (as you should) using a `for (i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++)` construct, yes, it will iterate over the "holes" as well. If you iterate using `for (i in array)` (which you shouldn't in the case of an array), then you'll get only the index that are actually set (but you'll also get any other non-numerical properties, including inherited ones). It's strongly recommended you use splice (if you want to edit in place) or filter (to generate a new array), though of course YMMV depending on your specific circumstances.